# Disable AJAX update of inline Drupal fields

Tags: drupal-7

I'm attempting to build a simple form using Drupal's editableviews module. The problem is that I want to modify the module so that instead of updating a given field's values via a change event and an AJAX call, I want to require a click of the Save button.

I think the AJAX update functionality is provided by the Entity API, but I'm not sure how to disable this when the fields are rendered in the view. Any ideas?

Comment: Entity API does not provide that kind of ajax, I believe it is provided by the module. Or the module make use of the Form API `#ajax`

Comment: Ahh, maybe it is Form API. I noticed the language and functionality of the Ajax saving was the same with editablefields as with editableviews so I figured it came from a common dependency.